# I need something to automate web browser tasks in its own virtual enviorment (Chrome)

Tags: java, browser, automation

Ever since i started learning java i wanted to create a way to automate  a few actions on a couple websites,

For example, [topline](https://www.jointopline.com/?fid=MG5N25TYHV24) is a website that replaces all your ads with its own ads and pays you a bit of money for it, i want to emulate the act of just surfing the web, then start emulating specific tasks like clicking certain buttons or playing flash games (Actually playing the game by using image recognition) and this has to be written in java as i want to run this on a raspberry pi.

any help is appreciated, is there a class that i can use?

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why should your Raspberry Pi be restricted to run only java applications?

Comment: it wouldn't, but i want the program to be multiplatform friendly. Also I have experience with Java more then anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a good browser automation tool. Refer http://seleniumhq.org/

You can get more info on Google. Let me know if you need help finding resources.

Answer (score 0):

Check the class [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), it will help you to emulate mouse interactions with the screen, but you have to implement the image recognition though

Comment: I wish to create a sort of virtual environment just like the one they use in runescape(Powerbot) to automate clicks and such. Detect images and not load certain images for example to minimize impact on ram. thanks for the feedback, keep it coming PRS. I have also found something that could possibly help me with my task, but does not seem to be quite up to it http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/getting-started/automating-browser-actions.aspx

Comment: You can also use [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) addon (firefox and ie) for task automation

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't point you to a JAVA solution, I would like to advocate two very interesting tools: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/installation.html). The latter depends on the first, and with them, browser navigation scripting and testing are a breeze.

They both work on Linux, MAC OS and Windows and are as multiplatform as Javascript can be. Naturally, it will work just fine in you Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I understand, but being undetectable is not listed as a requirement on your question.